# How to wrap two different tabs with different context in React Navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My React Native app has a Tab Navigator with two tabs, simple like that:

```js
<Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Public"
    component={PublicNavigator}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: () => <Ionicons name="ios-navigate" size={24} />,
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Private"
    component={PrivateNavigator}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: () => <Ionicons name="ios-pin" size={24} />,
    }}
  />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Since the screens within these two tabs have to access two different APIs and since I am using [Apollo Client 3.x](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/), the easy way would be to wrap these two screens so that they can access their respective clients, like that:

```js
<Tab.Navigator>
  <ApolloProvider
    client={
      new ApolloClient({
        uri: '/graphql/public',
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      })
    }>
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Public"
      component={PublicNavigator}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: () => <Ionicons name="ios-navigate" size={24} />,
      }}
    />
  </ApolloProvider>
  <ApolloProvider
    client={
      new ApolloClient({
        uri: '/graphql/public',
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      })
    }>
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Private"
      component={PrivateNavigator}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: () => <Ionicons name="ios-pin" size={24} />,
      }}
    />
  </ApolloProvider>
</Tab.Navigator>
```

However, this is not allowed by React Navigation, the returned error is: `A Navigator can only contain Screen components as its direct children`.

Now, I can wrap the child navigators themselves whenever I try to render them but the problem I have is that this would re-create the client every time the navigator re-renders, which seems to be pretty often.

Anyone else has another idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: Hi. Could you solve this? I need to do the same, one context for each tab. Thanks

Comment: I wasn’t able to find an easy solution either. The best I could do is save the Apollo client in the navigators’ state.

Answer (score 0):

You make the screen into a component, then wrap that `navigator`. Then place that component in the `tabNavigator`.

I believe this is the solution that would work for you.

```
const MainStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function MainStackScreen() {
  return (
  <ListContextWrapper>

    <MainStack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="MainScreen"
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        headerShown: false,
      })}
    >
      <MainStack.Screen name="MainScreen" component={MainScreen} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="FilterModal" component={FilterModal} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="DescriptionModal" component={DescriptionModal} />
    </MainStack.Navigator>
  </ListContextWrapper>

  );
}
```

then in your tabNavigator:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
     ...
    <Tab.Screen name="Main" component={MainStackScreen}
    </Tab.Navigator>
 />
```